# jQuery Navigation fade,hide,show,bounce and timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, navigation

Here goes a really simple question!
I want to make a navigation menu and content with jQuery.

Here is my navigation links :

```
<div id="menu" class="menuBg">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="btn1" href="#">How To?</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn2" href="#">Prizes?</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn3" href="#">Rules</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn4" href="#">Score</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Content :

```
<div id="content">

<div id="MainPage"><!-- content goes here --></div>
<div id="HowTo"><!-- content goes here --></div>
<div id="Prizes"><!-- content goes here --></div>
<div id="Rules"><!-- content goes here --></div>
<div id="Score"><!-- content goes here --></div>

</div>
```

Sample Navigation Code (includes first links code) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#baslaBtn').on('click', function(){

            $('#HowTo').hide();
            $('#Prizes').hide();
            $('#Rules').hide();
            $('#Score').hide();

             $("#MainPage").fadeOut(500,"linear", function() {
                    $("#soru1").slideToggle(function() {
                                $("#soru1").effect("fadeIn",2000);
                    }).show(2000);
             });

            $('#MainPage').hide(1000);

         });
 });
```

...and i have 5 more on('click') function to navigate my menu to my contents. The problem is every time all of these contents loading without any effect. I want to load my content when load process is finished. The other problem is i'm putting **hide()** in every function to hide other objects.

Is there any way to make a function without a repeated code like :

```
        $('#HowTo').hide();
        $('#Prizes').hide();
        $('#Rules').hide();
        $('#Score').hide();
```

And i want to show my contents opening with simple fadeIn effect. If i click the other links all objects will hide them self or fadeOut, new content object's goes load and will open with fadeIn effect.

P.S : When i load my content to  i can't use the content features like jquery.scroll plug in..All of them are disabling themself.

Really confused. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: by the way, see [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/186879) if you need help with a question ban.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté wow i'm back. thanks so much .. Now i'll find you when i'm in trouble you know that right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're going to fade all divs inside `#content` and `#soru1` is the div you want to show, you could simply use this:

```
$('#content div').fadeOut(function() {
    $("#soru1").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

This will fade every div inside `#content`.

To fade only specific divs and not every div element inside `#content`, you can change your code into this, as example:

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="MainPage" class='toFade'><!-- content goes here --></div>
    <div id="HowTo"><!-- content goes here --></div>
    <div id="Prizes class='toFade'"><!-- content goes here --></div>
    <div id="Rules"><!-- content goes here --></div>
    <div id="Score" class='toFade'><!-- content goes here --></div>

</div>
```

And do the following:

```
$('#content .toFade').fadeOut( function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

Then, only the selected divs would fade.

Comment: thanks @Felipe .. but its not working. i mean i have to reload my content data when i click the nav links. and when i do that it does moving somewhere i don't want to :)